# Kurento - Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://<ipaddress>:8433/kurento.

Tags: websocket, webrtc, spring-websocket, wss, kurento

I am facing issue while running sample kurento turorial for javascript.

Below is the exception in the browser console

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://:8433/kurento.

Sample tutorial for Java spring boot application working fine. I am able to stream from server.

Is there any configuration or setting changes are required for it.

Thanks
Mohsin

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether wss:// can be tested from fire fox.. we may have to use something like below to test wss connection

https://www.websocket.org/echo.html